# How to read solubility graph

Tags: solubility

[image]

The following table is showing the solubility of CO2 at different pressures.

However, I cannot figure out how to read this graph. The y-axis is molar fraction so that should mean that its value = mol CO$_2$/(mol CO$_2$ + mol H$_2$O). The journal that I got this graph from does not specify how many moles/what mass of water is used. Can I assume that it's 1 and that the y-axis is actually just the moles of CO$_2$

Comment: Remember that molar fraction is an intensive property http://www.wonderwhizkids.com/conceptmaps/thermodynamic_properties.html

Comment: Given some amount of dissolved CO2, how would you calculate the molar fraction?

Comment: would't it be the way i have mentioned in my question?